# Convert an Excel date code to a "date"

Tags: code-golf, date, conversion

Given a non-negative integer Excel-style date code, return the corresponding "date" in any reasonable form that clearly shows year, month, and "day".

Trivial, you may think. Did you notice the "scare quotes"? I used those because Excel has some quirks. Excel counts days with number 1 for January 1<sup>st</sup>, 1900, but [as if 1900 had a January 0<sup>th</sup> and a February 29<sup>th</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBHgY.png), so be very careful to try all test cases:

```
 Input → Output (example format)
     0 → 1900-01-00    Note: NOT 1899-12-31
     1 → 1900-01-01
     2 → 1900-01-02
    59 → 1900-02-28
    60 → 1900-02-29    Note: NOT 1900-03-01
    61 → 1900-03-01
   100 → 1900-04-09
  1000 → 1902-09-26
 10000 → 1927-05-18
100000 → 2173-10-14
```

Comment: Does *every* year have a 0th of January and 29th of February or is 1900 the only anomaly?

Comment: 1900 is the anomaly.  Excel treats leap years correctly except for 1900 (which is *not* a leap year).  But that was for compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3, where the bug originated.

Comment: @Shaggy Only 1900 is anomalous.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Apparently, the Lotus 1-2-3 devs did it to save on leap year code, such that the rule simply became every fourth year. With good reason too; 1900 was far in the past, and 2100 is, well, in a while.

Comment: If 1900 is the only anomaly in Excel, but Lotus 1-2-3 treated *all* years divisible by 4 as leap years, then you have to wonder why Microsoft decided to make that one exception.  (But every day I ask why Microsoft made some inane decision.)

Comment: @RickHitchcock It may very well be that the original Lotus 1-2-3 couldn't handle Y2K, and so Microsoft decided to mimic that one issue, but otherwise stay right. Btw, the legacy lives on: .NET's OADate has epoch 1899-12-***30*** so that it will line up with Excel on all but the first two months of 1900, however this necessitates the `DayOfWeek` method because the original epoch, 1899-12-30 (or the fictive 1900-01-00) was chosen such that the weekday simply was the mod-7 of the day number, but that won't work with 1899-12-30.

Comment: Here's the story behind the "why" about Excel dates: [Joel on Software: My First BillG Review](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/). Informative (and entertaining) read.

Answer (score 13):

## Excel, 3(+7?)

```
=A1
```

with format

```
yyy/m/d
```

Pure port

Comment: The output format may of course vary according to your locale.

Comment: This only works on Excel for Windows.  Excel for a Mac has a number system that starts with dates in 1904, not 1900.  It will not report a date for any year in 1900, which are part of the test cases.  You may want to specify that this is Excel for Windows.

Comment: @Keeta For this to work on Excel for Mac, simply uncheck "Use 1904 date system" [in preferences](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel).

Comment: @BradC Although true, any change to the default configuration of a program is perfectly fine BUT must be included in the answer.  I comment this as a point to improve the answer.  I would say either switch the name of it to Excel for Windows, add the caveat, or switch to OpenOffice Calc (or similar, since they purposefully included the bug, too).  https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10037/bytes-for-changing-a-configuration-file-before-running-a-program

Answer (score 6):

## k (kdb+ 3.5), <s>55</s> <s>54</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
{$(`1900.01.00`1900.02.29,"d"$x-36526-x<60)0 60?x}
```

to test, paste this line in the q console:

```
k)-1@{$(`1900.01.00`1900.02.29,"d"$x-36526-x<60)0 60?x}'0 1 2 59 60 61 100 1000 10000 100000;
```

the output should be

```
1900.01.00
1900.01.01
1900.01.02
1900.02.28
1900.02.29
1900.03.01
1900.04.09
1902.09.26
1927.05.18
2173.10.14
```

`{` `}` is a function with argument `x`

`0 60?x` index of `x` among `0 60` or 2 if not found

`ˋ1900.01.00ˋ1900.02.29` a list of two symbols

`,` append to it

`"d"$` converted to a date

`x-36526` number of days since 1900 (instead of the default 2000)

`- x<60` adjust for excel's leap error

`(ˋ1900.01.00ˋ1900.02.29,"d"$x-36526-x<60)`@`0 60?x` juxtaposition means indexing - the "@" in the middle is implicit

`$` convert to string

Comment: For a different version of k (k5/k6, I think), ```{$[x;$`d$x-65746;"1900.01.00"]}``` [seems to work](https://i.imgur.com/mIji4Mq.png). I assume something overflows somewhere for `100000`.

Comment: @zgrep You should post since versions of K basically are entirely dissimilar languages.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 111 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
n=input()
print('1900-0'+'12--0209'[n>9::2],date(1900,1,1)+timedelta(n+~(n>59)))[0<n!=60]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsMgEEDRfU6Rrhyrwii0YGhykZBFIIYKdRSZLrrp1Q2uP@@XH78zudbOmtN47Bw4pjDGVHLl@0BzpPJlkEOpkRiE9YgGhRLWGYMOvVhp8dPkNt0x9K6ttlL1zxE@vAOpP9Dy8FLKFV90m5@4tWYRLw)

-5 thanks to [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn).

Comment: Note: I'm pretty sure this will turn out to be longer as a lambda, since the format of the result shouldn't vary.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>89 82</s>  77 bytes

*Saved  <s>7</s>  12 bytes thanks to @tsh*

```javascript
n=>(p=n>60?'':19)+new Date(p*400,0,n-!p||1).toJSON().slice(p/9,10-!n)+(n&&'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdHBTsMwDAbgO0@RXdaE1a3tdt0yqePCiUN3GC9QlQwNVUlFK7js3Us7IWAhOTqf5d/yW/1R9837uRvAuhcznsrRlnvZlXZf4EMU7UirlTWf4rEejOzuc8QYYwuL7nIhlQzu6XiopEr69txM/6mOCWFh1Ura5TKK1Ng427vWJK17lScp5odKiTQVpBEBCRDnYuUGsxPV4VnQVmsghozuAs3kNQcRe4gDaK3/IgbeBlCBHtJe1ms9C8cobrKGEeHNhBxQ/0OT@UU8CeDCR7P5QbwBXAP5C13NN2LaZDCdivLxCw)

Comment: `n=>n?n-60?new Date(1900,0,n-(n>60)).toJSON().slice(0,10):'1900-02-29':'1900-01-00'`

Comment: @tsh That's much better indeed. Thanks. (Also, I wonder if [this approach](https://tio.run/##bc@xbsIwEAbgvU/hoUKOxIW7CxiMBF2YOoSBbFWlRNRUoMhGxGqHimdPE1pBce3JOn2/7r9D9VE129P@6MG6N9PuFq1dLEvSiIAMrIufLwFi8fhlzadYVd7IfjrEoQVplwqTJPXuebPOZXIu0@ZY731ZlC/2yYLCwYDn9NpunW1cbdLavcudFP3rcmI0ErcN/TB33sxFvi4EzbQGYsjoIRKmIBxFHCCOoIn@i7qbZxGkMEA66HqZZ/Ea6q5rHBHebRgD6n@oMzfEnQBWIerNFfEUcAIUHnQxv4hpmgEh0Lj9Bg) could somehow be golfed.)

Comment: I just find out `new Date(0,0,1)` is same as `new Date(1900,0,1)`. So remove `190` saves 3 bytes. And...

Comment: 77 bytes: `n=>(p=n>60?'':19)+new Date(p*400,0,n-!p||1).toJSON().slice(p/9,10-!n)+(n&&'')`

Comment: Does it need to be run in GMT0/-x?

Comment: @tsh Very clever hacks in there!

Comment: @l4m2 Yes. And TIO happened to be configured in UTC timezone.

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>205</s> 189 bytes

```
import StdEnv
a=30;b=31;c=1900;r=rem
@m=sum(take m(?c))
?n=[b,if(n>c&&(r n 4>0||r n 100<1&&r n 400>0))28 29,b,a,b,a,b,b,a,b,a,b: ?(n+1)]
$n#m=while(\m= @m<n)inc 0-1
=(c+m/12,1+r m 12,n- @m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BS8NAEIXv@RUDlrBLEpxNPVjTSXrQg@CtR@ths011MTOVTaoI/e2uq4gPHnw83jDPjYOVyMf9aRyArZfo@e0YZtjO@zt5zywtselpaRpHZoXYBAoDZxum6cRqtq/pSnVO66wTeuxLf1DSujxXAQSuWjyff8Agrk2e/2aILWpdX0O9KvvS/vmfbqBTUhj9lC3kgunjxY@D2jHBhteivTjAymSkXMGXpi5NEYAhgVSpoeN2tmk8wSK9TIpf7jDa5ylW9w/x9lMsezd9Aw)

Comment: First answer that doesn't use built-in date handling. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 31 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Returns date as `[Y,M,D]`

```apl
(¯3↑×-60∘≠)+3↑2⎕NQ#263,60∘>+⊢-×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb/NQ6tN37UNvHwdF0zg0cdMx51LtDUBgkYAZX4BSobmRnrgCXstB91LdI9PP1/GlDbo96@R13NEJ1AdcFBzkAyxMMz@H8JULb6Ue/WR50Li4DMtEe9u6zU87PVH3W3qKclZuaoAwWA0kW1XAYKJQqGlgYGCoYKBlyGCI4hlxGCY8RlagnjGSkYWXCZGSBxLbnM4BqNgRoNDeCyJgqWIC6Ub6RgqWBkBhaAiBiZK5gqGFpAREBCRobmQBOAVpoAAA)

`×` sign of the date code

`⊢-` subtract that from the argument (the date code)

`60∘>+` increment if date code is above sixty

`2⎕NQ#263,` use that as immediate argument for "Event 263" (IDN to date)
 <sup>IDN is just like Excel's date code, but without Feb 29, 1900, and the day before Jan 1, 1900 is Dec 31, 1899</sup>

`3↑` take the first three elements of that (the fourth one is day of week)

`(`…`)+` add the following to those:

`60∘≠` 0 if date code is 60; 1 if date code is not 60

`×-` subtract that from the sign of the date code

`¯3↑` take the last three elements (there is only one) padding with (two) zeros

developed together with @Adám in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 43 bytes

Ended up with a part port of [Arnauld's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176683/58974).

Output is in `yyyy-m-d` format.

```
?U-#<?Ð#¾0TUaU>#<)s7:"1900-2-29":"1900-1-0"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3z5UV9nG/vAE5UP7DEJCE0PtlG00i82tlAwtDQx0jXSNLJWgbENdA6X//w0A) or [test 0-100](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3z5UV9nG/vAE5UP7DEJCE0PtlG00i82tlAwtDQx0jXSNLJWgbENdA6X//w0NDLl0c4MA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>186</s> 185 bytes

```cs
using System;class P{static void Main(){var i=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());Console.Write((i==0|i==60)?$"1900-{i%59+1}-{i%31}":DateTime.FromOADate(i+(i<60?1:0)).ToString("yyyy-M-d"));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5RC4IwHMS/ypCCDZlMIkFNJIqekiSFnof@iT/oBtsSxPzspg/dw3G/e7lrLG@0gWX5WFRvUo3WQZ82nbSWlJN10mFDBo0tKSQqyqZBGoIZKheU0ligF62s7iB4gmzvqIAylv67l0EHlGKWie9qkWD5zgtjIfiE@2Psh/MWDuHsJVfpoMYegpvR/eO8IUWf4ikSeZgIxoJaV86sH6k3ruIFb711ap6XJRI/)

---

-1 byte by replacing OR operator(||) with binary OR operator(|).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 81 bytes

```perl6
{$_??$_-60??Date.new-from-daycount($_+15018+(60>$_))!!'1900-02-29'!!'1900-01-00'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxLCoMwFIXhrVwlbRJM5CZgqAPNpPsIoSaj@sBaiohrT6W0nfyHb3KmMN9N6lc4R2jSRpy1xEmD1l79EsohvGScx152fr2Nz2FhxBWqQnUpmMGWOM6zjKoaUaKWuqZ/KYlI9/TwK@RbGfuF0ZPpKN@haWGLxw/fc4jjDChACdACqlqAOWQOKsRPvv0Npjc)

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, <s>141 95</s> 94 bytes

```
SELECT IIF(n=0,'1/0/1900',IIF(n=60,'2/29/1900',
FORMAT(DATEADD(d,n,-IIF(n<60,1,2)),'d')))FROM i
```

Line break is for readability only.

Input is taken via pre-existing table **i** with integer field **n**, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

SQL uses a similar (but corrected) 1-1-1900 starting point for its internal date format, so I only have to offset it by 1 or 2 days in the `DATEADD` function.

SQL can't output a column containing a mix of date and character values, so I can't leave off the `FORMAT` command (since it would then try to convert `1/0/1900` to a date, which is of course invalid).

What's nice about SQL is that I can load up all the input values into the table and run them all at once. My (US) locality defaults to a `m/d/yyyy` date format:

```
n       output
0       1/0/1900
1       1/1/1900
2       1/2/1900
59      2/28/1900
60      2/29/1900
61      3/1/1900
100     4/9/1900
1000    9/26/1902
10000   5/18/1927
43432   11/28/2018
100000  10/14/2173
```

**EDIT**: Saved 46 bytes by changing to a nested `IIF()` instead of the much more verbose `CASE WHEN`.

**EDIT 2**: Saved another byte by moving the `-` in front of the `IIF`.